# Every apt-get install returns flashplugin error, but install works

Tags: software-installation, flash

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 using wubi. I am now still in the process of installing my development environments. I have seen the following error occur multiple times.

For example, just now I wanted to install `vim` using the commmand `sudo apt-get install vim`. The following error is returned:

```
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:  
("Errors were encountered while processing:" [via Google Translate])
  flashplugin-downloader:i386
  flashplugin-installer
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The install seems to have completed and I can now use `vim`. Still, I would like to know what this error is and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error simply means flashplugin-installer didn't install correctly before, and you will need to reinstall it.

Run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

This flashplugin problem often happen when you are behind proxy. Right now, flashplugin-installer does not work if you are behind a proxy, bcause it tries to download it directly, not via the proxy. Even if you applied the settings systemwide.

My workaround is, the following:

Two things need to be done:

- Edit your `/etc/environment` file and add the following line to it: `HTTP_PROXY="http://your_proxy_addess:proxy_port"`
- Edit your sudoers file by sudo visudo (use the EDITOR environment variable to specify the editor if you don't like vi), and add the following line before the `Defaults env_reset` one: `Defaults env_keep="http_proxy"`

Now it should install fine, via `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

If the update notifier bugs you on every startup, you may want to delete this file:

`/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/flashplugin-installer.failed`

Comment: update notifier was bugging me a lot with flash-plugin installer. thanks for the last hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also behind proxy. Thank you Calmarius.

As root, I typed these lines in the terminal to get flashplugin installed:

- `export http_proxy=http://192.168.0.1:8080`
- `apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

Comment: I'm unsure about the answer I gave here. In one of the two machines I did that, flashplugin keeps prompting me to re-install.